# How to fade in a table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

I want to create a page where a table would be faded in as it loads (from transparent to opaque). I've tried using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table1').hide();
    $('#table1').fadeIn(1000);
  });
```

And it kind of works, but the table shows up, quickly disappears and then smoothly fades in. Is there a way to achieve the fadein without the table appearing beforehand?

Comment: (Offtopic) in the future if you'll need something similar you can **simply do:** `$('#table1').hide().fadeIn(1000);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening:

- the table is 'display:table;' by default.
- the browser reads the DOM and displays the table
- jQuery hides the table and does the animation

Set inside your CSS `display:none;` for your table:

```
#table1{
   display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#table1').fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that if the table is a div table i.e. `display: table`, then this will not work because the fadeIn function will set the display property to `block`, breaking the table layout. You'd have to wrap your table in another div, set the display of that to none in CSS and do the fading on that element.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this by applying a

> display:none

style to the table, however this then draws accessibility issues as users without javascript won't be able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Just set your table to display:none in your CSS and then remove the initial hide

CSS

```
#table1{display:none}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table1').fadeIn(1000);
})
```

The jQuery is not fired until the whole page and it's dependencies have loaded (the $(document).ready function) but the table is shown on the page as soon as it has loaded which will always be before the jQuery fires. Once the jQuery fires, it hides the table and then fades it back in. You just need to hide it with the CSS and then fade it in. Easy :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete solution for fade In your table using jQuery.

1) Include latest jQuery.js and JQuery-UI java script files in header tag first.

**2) HTML:**

```
<table id="table1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" width="50%">
  <tr>
    <th>
      Column1
    </th>
    <th>
      Column2
    </th>
    <th>
      Column3
    </th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      data1 
    </td>
    <td>
      data2 
    </td>
    <td>
      data3 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**3) CSS:**

```
#table1{
  border:1px solid #556688;
  background:#eee;
  display:none;
}
th{
  text-align:left;
}
td,th{
  border:1px solid #556688;
}
```

**4) JQuery in script tag:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table1').fadeIn(10000);
});
```

Try it on bins: http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpaj

Answer (score 0):

Use `dispay:none` in your CSS to have the table hidden before fading it in.

Answer (score 0):

The table shows up in the first place because Javascript is executed after the DOM is loaded. You should hide the table initially by using display:none in your css.